# I don't know how to make query for extract unknown sender in splunk

Tags: splunk

There is SMTP and DNS traffic in `sourcetype`. I want to extract any unknown sender's email in SMPT based on DNS traffic.

So, I'm trying to get the sender email that does not belong to the DNS host, but I don't know how to do it.

```
index=payload sourcetype="stream:smtp"
| rex field=sender_mail "\@<?host>.*"
[ search index=payload sourcetype="stream:dns" NOT host ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the rex extraction, the question mark (*?*) needs to be outside the *capture group*.
See some examples here, not sure if the capture group I imagined actually matches your input
https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.6/SearchReference/Rex

Also mind the *host* filed is a special one and it's used to a lot of splunk events so you may want to not try to overload it. With the first extraction, extracting a field called host can conflict the existing host field found in your *stream:smtp* sourcetype. I would recommend using another name altogether

```
index=payload sourcetype="stream:smtp" OR sourcetype="stream:dns"
| eval hosti=host
| rex field=sender_mail "\@(?<hosti>.*?)\s"
| chart count over hosti by sourcetype
| where 'stream:dns'=0
```